# if $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$ then $p\mid \gcd(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> I would like to prove the following property :
>
> $$\forall (p,a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^{3} \quad p\mid a \mbox{ and } p\mid b \implies p\mid \gcd(a,b)$$

Knowing that :

### Definition

> Given two natural numbers $a$ and $b$, not both zero, their *greatest common divisor* is the largest divisor of $a$ and $b$.

- If $\operatorname{Div}(a)$ denotes the set of divisors of $a$, the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is $\gcd(a,b)=\max(\operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b))$
- $$d=\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\iff \begin{cases}d\in \operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b) & \\ & \\  \forall x \in \operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b): x\leq d \end{cases}$$
- $$\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}\quad a\mid b \iff Div(a) \subset Div(b)$$
- $$\forall  x\in \mathbb{Z}\quad \operatorname{Div}(x)=\operatorname{Div}(-x)  $$
- If $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(|a|,|b|)$, adding $\gcd(0,0)=0$

Indeed,

Let $(p,a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^{3} $ such that $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$ then :

$p\mid a \iff \operatorname{Div}(p)\subset \operatorname{Div}(a)$ and $p\mid b \iff \operatorname{Div}(p)\subset \operatorname{Div}(b)$ then

$\operatorname{Div}(p)\subset \left( \operatorname{Div}(a)\cap \operatorname{Div}(b)\right) \iff p\mid \gcd(a,b)$

Am I right?

Comment: @  yes of cours in the context of divisibility

Comment: What is $capDiv$?

Comment: As far as I believe, your proof is perfectly fine but you must mention beforehand that the $Div$ function gets a set of the prime divisors of a number.

Comment: If you already know $\operatorname{Div}(\gcd(a,b))=\operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b)$ you have nothing to prove.

Comment: yes so i will remove it

Comment: The last implication still uses Div$(\gcd(a,b)) = $Div$(a)\cap$Div$(b)$.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what definition of greatest common divisor you use. You probably use the second one.

### Definition 1

> Given natural numbers $a$ and $b$, the natural number $d$ is their *greatest common divisor* if
>
> 1. $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$
> 2. for all $c$, if $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b$, then $c\mid d$

**Theorem.** The greatest common divisor exists and is unique.

*Proof.* Euclidean algorithm.

### Definition 2

> Given two natural numbers $a$ and $b$, not both zero, their *greatest common divisor* is the largest divisor of $a$ and $b$.

If $\operatorname{Div}(a)$ denotes the set of divisors of $a$, the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is $\gcd(a,b)=\max(\operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b))$

### Extension to $\mathbb{Z}$, for both definitions

If $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(|a|,|b|)$, adding $\gcd(0,0)=0$ for definition 2.

### Proof of the statement using definition 1

With this definition, the statement is obvious.

### Proof of the statement using definition 2

Let $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$. We need to show that $p\mid\gcd(a,b)$. It is not restrictive to assume $p,a,b>0$.

*It is true that $\operatorname{Div}(p)\subseteq\operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b)$, but this just implies that $p\le\gcd(a,b)$, not that it is a divisor thereof.*

The proof can be accomplished by using the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=ax+by$ for some integers $x$ and $y$ (Bézout's theorem). With this it is easy: $a=pr$, $b=ps$, so
$$
\gcd(a,b)=ax+by=prx+psy=p(rx+sy)
$$

How to prove Bézout's theorem is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Yeah thank you this is great explanation but note that $$\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}\quad a\mid b \iff Div(a) \subset Div(b) $$

Comment: @Educ Yes, but you have an intersection to cope with and you didn't prove that $\operatorname{Div}(\gcd(a,b))=\operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b)$ (which is precisely the statement you want to prove).

Comment: $\operatorname{Div}(\gcd(a,b))=\operatorname{Div}(a)\cap\operatorname{Div}(b)$ this can be proven by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: @Educ Yes, of course; but you have to state what you have available. As it stands, your proof is not sufficient.

Comment: alright i will edit my question to state what i have available

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is:

By [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), we know that for all $(a, b)$, $\exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}. ax + by = \gcd(a, b)$.

So we have to prove that:

$$p|ax+by$$

Since, $p|a \implies a = pk_1$ and $p|b \implies b = pk_2$ for $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

$$\implies p|pk_1x + pk_2y$$
$$\implies p|p(k_1x + k_2y)$$
which is true.

Comment: Thank you but what about my proof

Comment: @Educ As far as I believe, your proof is perfectly fine but you must mention beforehand that the $Div$ function gets a set of the prime divisors of a number.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Possible correction, when you write " $\exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ ", I believe it is not necessary for $x,y$ to be positive, so it should be $\exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. For example we know $\gcd(4,10) = 2$ but there is no way $4x + 10y $ can equal to $2$ if we insist that $x, y$ are positive.

Answer (score 1):

One line proof using ring theory: $(a) \subset (p), (b) \subset (p) \implies (a,b) \subset (p)$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is PID implies $(a,b)$ is principal. We are done.