# Gcd of two number divides each other

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

(a) Prove that $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) | \operatorname{gcd}\left(3 a+b, a^{3}\right)$

Since say $d = gcd(a,b)$ then $d|a$ and $d|b$ this will imply $d|(3a+b)$ and $d|a^3$ and therfore $d$ is divisor of those two.But how to show it is greatest common divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic properties of $e = \gcd(f,g)$ is that if $d \mid f$ and $d \mid g$, then $d$ is a common divisor, so it must also divide the greatest common divisor, i.e., $d \mid e$. As shown in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1771428/602049) of [if $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$ then $p\mid \gcd(a,b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771373/if-p-mid-a-and-p-mid-b-then-p-mid-gcda-b), its definition #$1$ uses this explicitly, with a second definition being provable using [Bezout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) (basically, if $d = \gcd(a,b)$, then $ax + by = d$ for some integers $x,y$, so if $e \mid a$ and $e \mid b$, then $e \mid ax + by = d$). You can also use the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) to show this using prime factorizations, but I won't go into details about that here.

With this concept, you've basically proven what you're asking to show, i.e., with $d = \gcd(a,b)$, then $d \mid 3a + b$ and $d \mid a^3$, so $\gcd(a,b) \mid \gcd(3a + b, a^3)$.

Comment: How to show this property of gcd?

Comment: @mathsstudent I've updated my answer to explain this.